# Update of SelectedItem does not update the displayed value

Tags: wpf, combobox, rename, selecteditem

I thought there were tons of answers in the net, but strangely none seems to fit my issue.

Simple enough: I have a wpf project with a comboBox whose SelectedItem is bound to my ViewModel (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged). The ItemsSource of my ComboBox is bound to a CollectionViewSource's View.

[all property names in this example a fictional, they shall just illustrate things so one get's the drift]

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource = "{Binding MyCollectionViewSource.View}" 
SelectedItem = "{Binding MyItem, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
SelectedIndex = "{Binding MyIndex}"
</ComboBox>
```

The CollectionViewSource's source is an ObservableCollection.

```
MyCollectionViewSource.Source = MyObservableCollection;
```

Now, I have a Textbox. The comboBox shows strings. The SelectedItem is shown in the TextBox - therefore the user can change that string (re-name the SelectedItem of the ComboBox) and click a button, that holds the UpdateContentCommand.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
```

Now, it does what it's supposed to do - but not in detail.

The SelectedItem shown in the ComboBox (more exactly: it's display, when dropdown is closed) has say  a value of 'dog'. If I re-name it in the TextBox to 'cat', it still shows 'dog'. If I click on the ComboBox, and the dropdown appears, I can see there is no more item called 'dog', but one named 'cat'.

So, a workaround I found is as follows:

right in my Command-Method I set the SelectedIndex to -1, directly followed by SelectedIndex = 0 (or whichever index my SelectedItem has). This way it looks as if re-naming the SelectedItem did instantaneously update it.

So far I tried:

- UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged in my XAML
- Mode = TwoWay in XAML
- MyCollectionViewSource.View.Refresh() in the command-method in my viewModel.

But nothing worked so far, and my workaround is more a hack.

Do I miss something obvious??

Comment: "*all property names in this example a fictional*" - better show us your actual code, and explain how the MyText property is related to the others. Also show the implementations of all relevant properties. And perhaps explain why you use a CollectionView instead of directly binding the ItemsSource to MyObservableCollection. And why you bind both SelectedItem and SelectedIndex.

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the SelectedItem Binding is pointless. Both are the default anyway, as for SelectedIndex.

Comment: @Clemens: CollectionViewSource is because that's my default - filtering is outherwise a pita. As for the whole code: really, there is nothing fancy going on - btw. my object gets updated - only the combobox, the string that is displayed stays the same, when it is changed. I see this is some default behaviour, but I don't think it isn't unchangeable.